# ltugboat class and improper \beginR, \endR in XeTeX

Tags: xetex, arabic, bidi

The `ltugboat` class is incompatible with the `bidi` package so I am attempting to obtain minimal Arabic script support without the use of `bidi` or `polyglossia`. The minimum I need is to be able to use the `\beginR` and `\endR` primitives. But when I use these primitives with the `ltugboat` class I get the error message:

```
! Improper \beginR.
<recently read> \beginR 
                        
l.102 Hamza&4F&\texttt{h}&\myarabicx{^^^^0626}
                                              \\
! Improper \endR.
\myarabicx ...{\beginR \arabicfont #1\hfill \endR 
                                                  }
```

Could you please tell what it means for `\beginR` and `\endR` to be *improper*, and how I can avoid this error?

(XeLaTeX has been compiled with eTeX support and with some other class, these primitives work fine.)

Comment: Try `\TeXXeTstate=1` before using `\beginR`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that what's happening here is not merely a function of `ltugboat` as evidenced by this MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\newfontfamily{\arabicfont}{FreeSerif}[Script=Arabic]


\begin{document}

\newcommand{\myarabic}[1]{\beginR\arabicfont #1\endR}

\myarabic{^^^^0626}

\end{document}
```

I had to dig into the source code to discover that what's going on is that you're using the old TeX-XeT primitives which are *not* turned on by default. There's a new primitive, `\TeXXeTstate` which will turn it on (just add `\TeXXeTstate=1` to the preamble).

I had guessed that there was some modern handling of this in XeTeX and a different preferred route, but digging into the `bidi` code, it turns out that they use `\TeXXeTstate` themselves for XeTeX engines. (It's worth also noting that they use a modified version of the Knuth-MacKay algorithms from 1987 where they reverse the characters at shipout rather than requiring special IVD-DVI handling as the original code did.

Comment: Thank you so much Don! The least I can say is that this feature is not sufficiently documented…

Comment: @yannis This is true, The XeTeX user guide doesn't mention this flag or anything other than font loading, really. Digging through source code is not the best discovery method.

Answer (score 0):

For reference, LuaLaTeX can also do package-less Arabic support very minimally.

[image: no packages]

It could be an alternate option.

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily{\arabicfont}{FreeSerif}[Script=Arabic]
\newcommand{\myarabic}[1]{{\textdir TRT \pardir TRT\arabicfont #1}}

\begin{document}

\myarabic{^^^^0626 ب ببب ت تتت ص صصص}

\end{document}
```